# iPhones jQuery show/hide conflict with auto scrolling slideshows

Tags: jquery, iphone

There seems to be an issue with iPods and iPhones (4,4S, and probably 5).  We have an autoscrolling slideshow utilizing Flex Slider.  I have a toggle trigger to show and hide our menu (div). When the menu is toggled open and the slideshow auto scrolls to the next image the menu closes.  On my Android phone (Android OS 4.1) it seems to work perfectly fine.

Seems like the iDevices are having issues with the Javascript.  Would this be a correct assumption?  Anyone have a possible idea or solution to my issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no. It does not makes sense at all. The only thing that I can imagine is that some elements are sharing name-specific attributes (classes, or even ID). OR might be your click handlers are not prevented from propagation. A well written plugin should not interfer with any other element on your page. And I think *Flex* is well-written. Anyway, hard to answer without having a crystal sphere.

Comment: I think I found my culprit.  I am wrapping my toggle in a window resize function to detect the screen size and show or hide the full navigation menu.  @roXon thanks for the feedback.  Flex is very well written and works great.  I took out the window resize detection and it seems work fine now.  Will mark it as my own issue. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad you found the nasty bug! :)

Comment: It is still a bug only with iPhones and iPods though so the solution is not a complete great fix. Oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit. I was wrapping my code in $(window).resize function to detect the screen size to show the menu if the screen size is over 480px.  This seems to have fixed my issue.  I took it out of the resize.
Below is my original code. Don't use it. It is for what NOT to do.  If anyone has an idea on how to fix it maybe that would help but this seems to not work.  Seems like it causes a conflict between my auto scrolling Flex slider or any other animated sliders.

//Menu show hide

```
   $(window).load(function(){
var $window = $(window);
var $topNav = $('#mainNavTop');
var $utilContent = $('#utilityContent');
function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();
 if(windowsize < 480){
    $('#mainNavTop,#utilityContent').css('display','none');
    $('.mobileNavIcon').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $topNav.toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });

    $('.mobileSearchIcon').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $utilContent.toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
}
    else{
    $('#mainNavTop,#utilityContent').css('display','block');
    }
 }
// Execute on load
checkWidth();
// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```